# how to update the data through Room and display some message to user after the update

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

We want to show some message to the user after the update using the code as below. The code failed in the stress test. The error showing

> IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from given view. Please provide a valid view

for snackbar part.

Our guess is fragment was already destroyed before database update was done. What is the best way to handle this? We try not to add check for the view or fragment.

AppExecutos is the same as [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceMigrationsSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/migrations/AppExecutors.java) one.

```
mAppExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
    boolean result = mViewModel.update(...);
    if (result) {
        mAppExecutors.mainThread().execute(() -> {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(),"Updated!",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
        });
    } else {
        mAppExecutors.mainThread().execute(() -> {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(),"Failed!",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Call the update method from ViewModel and observe for result in the Fragment. The ViewModel should get destroyed when the Fragment gets destroyed too, and hence you won't get into a crash as Snackbar show() won't happen when the ViewModel stops observing. Ideally, you should introduce a Repository layer to handle/switch threads, but not directly in the Parent view itself.

Comment: You will need something like this:  viewModel.update().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean result) {
                if (result) { // Show snackbar  }
            }
        });

Comment: Thank you, @BadhrinathCanessane!
I also found this useful post - "LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)" (https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150).